# How do I convert a Django QuerySet into a Dictionary with List of Objects without iterating to the queryset?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I need to filter and map the result to a dictionary of string keys and list of object values. Something like in Java will result to `Map<String, List<SomeDbModel>>`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you give an example?

Comment: You will need to explain what your desired output is. Python doesn't have "maps" - do you mean a dict?

Comment: Yes, it would be a dictionary.

Comment: I was looking for something where I don't have to iterate and adding them to the list

Comment: Updated the title and question to be specific and not confusing

Comment: A dictionary of *what* to *what*? What are the keys? What are the values?

Comment: dictionary of string keys and values are any objects. i can iterate and add them manually via:
      `for item in items.iterator():
             my_dictionary[item.id].append(item)`